# Matlab - Apply a function to specific sub-dimensions of multidimensional array only

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I'd like to know if there is some possibility in Matlab to map a function only on the N x M part of a N x M x K array without using for-loops. Specifically, I have a N x M matrix containing vectors of length 3, so my overall structure is N x M x 3. Now I'd like to calculate the norm of each of these vectors, so it would be great to just apply a function which takes a 1 x 3 vector as input and which is applied to every cell of the N x M part "on top", resulting in a N x M x 1 array.

The way I'm doing it currently is by using for-loops and extracting the relevant part by indexing (i,j,:). Now I'm just curious if there's a better solution for it. :)
It seems to be possible for a N x M cellarray via cellfun, but I couldn't find any way to do it on normal arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Some Matlab functions such as *sum* allow you to specify a dimension in which to be executed.
Using the definition of norm, for an input array a:

```
sqrt(sum(a.^2,3))
```

should return the norm along the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can slice a matrix using num2cell or mat2cell and then apply cellfun
2. You can use arrayfun(@(x,y)... with x to be your matrix and y to be index. Another way is to use bsxfun

To save memory and time just send a part of your source data to cellfun if you don't want process the whole matrix